# Convert All Chars in String to Different Escaped Formats(Java)

Tags: java, decimal, hex, url-encoding, html-encode

I'm looking to convert characters in a string to different escaped formats like the following, where the letter 'a' is the string being converted:

```
hex-url: %61
hex-html: &#x61;
decimal-html: &#97
```

I've searched used various built-in methods, but they merely take out the url-encoding specified chars(like '<') and escape them. I want to escape the ENTIRE string. Is there any way to convert a string into the formats above in java(using built in libraries, preferrably)?

Comment: Some more detail would help. How about some expected inputs and expected outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class StringEncoders
{
    static public void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("hex-url: " + hexUrlEncode("a"));
        System.out.println("hex-html: " + hexHtmlEncode("a"));
        System.out.println("decimal-html: " + decimalHtmlEncode("a"));
    }
    static public String hexUrlEncode(String str)   {
        return encode(str, hexUrlEncoder);
    }
    static public String hexHtmlEncode(String str)  {
        return encode(str, hexHtmlEncoder);
    }
    static public String decimalHtmlEncode(String str)  {
        return encode(str, decimalHtmlEncoder);
    }
    static private String encode(String str, CharEncoder encoder)
    {
        StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder();
        for ( int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
            encoder.encode(str.charAt(i), buff);
        return ""+buff;
    }
    private static class CharEncoder
    {
        String prefix, suffix;
        int radix;
        public CharEncoder(String prefix, String suffix, int radix)        {
            this.prefix = prefix;
            this.suffix = suffix;
            this.radix = radix;
        }
        void encode(char c, StringBuilder buff)     {
            buff.append(prefix).append(Integer.toString(c, radix)).append(suffix);
        }
    }
    static final CharEncoder hexUrlEncoder = new CharEncoder("%","",16);
    static final CharEncoder hexHtmlEncoder = new CharEncoder("&#x",";",16);
    static final CharEncoder decimalHtmlEncoder = new CharEncoder("&#",";",10); 
}
```

Comment: Perfect! This serves my purpose. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about built in libraries, but it's pretty easy to write a method to do this yourself. All you need to do is loop through the string character by character and for each character do something like this:

`"&#"+Integer.toHexString(character)+";";`

and then append it to a new string you are making that has all the characters encoded.

Answer (score 0):

There is unlikely to be an existing library method that does what you want:

- In each of those examples, the escaping is unnecessary; e.g. for the letter 'a'.  Library methods that do escaping only do it if it is necessary.
- Libraries that allow you to do HTML / XML escaping don't allow you to chose the specific escaping syntax (AFAIK).
- Your third example is incorrectly escaped.

You will need to implement this yourself.  (The code is trivial ... and I'm assuming that you are capable.)